# How to debug Django app with Spyder (and breakpoints)

Tags: python, django, spyder

So I created a project but if I press run, of course execute the python file I am looking at so I need to specify to run the classic `manage.py` but as far I can see that configuration is not by project but globally.
So I can configure globally to run `manage.py runserver` and fix that issue easily but the second one is on how to connect for breakpoints usage without specify in the code for the pdb functions (I can find only that).
Months ago I forked the original django-pdb to bump the django support https://github.com/Mte90/django-pdb-extended but the problem is that execute pdb on the whole page automatically.
Online there aren't any information useful about Django for spyder, but also for Flask (to get inspiration for the configuration).

I am writing here to see if someone has more hints on to achieve to use that editor to develop (and debug) in Django.